# Tensorflow with GPU cuda8 compile error "__shfl_up"

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow 1.2.1
CUDA 8.0.61.2

When compiling tensorflow with bazel, I gets an error :

./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_kernel_helper.h(620): error: identifier "__shfl" is undefined

./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_kernel_helper.h(640): error: identifier "__shfl_up" is undefined

./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_kernel_helper.h(660): error: identifier "__shfl_down" is undefined

./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_kernel_helper.h(680): error: identifier "__shfl_xor" is undefined

4 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000010d3_00000000-7_depthtospace_op_gpu.cu.cpp1.ii".

How to solve this ?

gcc version 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-3) (GCC) 
Use compute 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a selection of unsupported computing ability (too low number). Minimum supported version is 3.0. I filed a bug on [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12181) on it. It should be now [fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/2133b83376a3439924a0bb9bac7b4a8b716a6fc0) in configure script so it's not possible to select Cuda computing ability lower than 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move from cuda 10.1 to cuda 9.1 `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and `gcc-7` to `gcc-5` . It worked for me after trying all solutions available so far.